# How to reinitialize ExoPlayer after releasing?

Tags: android, video, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have `ExoPlayerWrapper` class which is wrapper for `ExoPlayer` and is singleton injected by *Dagger*. Init block in `ExoPlayerWrapper` class looks in the following way:

```
@Singleton
class ExoPlayerWrapper @Inject constructor(
    context: Context,
    userAgentInfo: UserAgentInfo
) {
    private val exoPlayer: ExoPlayer
    private val httpDataSource: HttpDataSource
    private val mediaSourceFactory: ExtractorMediaSource.Factory

    override val exoPlayerInstance: ExoPlayer
        get() = exoPlayer

   init {
        ...
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector)
        httpDataSource = CustomHttpDataSource(userAgentInfo.userAgent, null)
        mediaSourceFactory = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory { httpDataSource }
        state = Player.STATE_IDLE
    }

   override fun playFromUrl(uri: Uri, headers: Map<String, String>) {
        reset()
        ...
        val mediaSource = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(uri)
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    }

    override fun pause() {
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
    }

    override fun reset() {
       stop()
       state = Player.STATE_IDLE
    }

    override fun stop() {
       exoPlayer.stop()
       exoPlayer.seekTo(0)
    }

    override fun seekTo(position: Long) {
       exoPlayer.seekTo(position)
    }

    ...

    override fun release() {
        exoPlayer.release()
        state = Player.STATE_RELEASED
    }
```

And in `onCreate()` method of `Activity` I have the following code:

```
public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player)
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        initialized = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(INITIALIZED)
    } 
    if (!initialized) {
        val uri = Uri.parse(attachedVideo?.uri)
        player.playFromUrl(uri, sessionStore.sessionHeaders)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        initialized = true
    }

    videoView.player = player.exoPlayerInstance

    backBtn.setOnClickListener{ _ ->
        player.release()
        finish()
    }
}
```

But in this case I can play only one video after click on `backBtn` button, other videos after that aren't played until I close app and reopen app again. And if I change `backBtn's OnClickListener` in the following way:

```
backBtn.setOnClickListener{ _ ->
    player.pause()
    finish()
}
```

all works fine, other videos are played after click on `backBtn` button. So it seems to be problem with reinitializing `ExoPlayer` after `release()` method invocation. And how correctly to reinitialize ExoPlayer after releasing?

**UPD**
And after `release()` invocation and after attempt to open video again I see the following error in Logcat:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {81fa8ef} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:545)
>     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:661)
>     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:630)
>     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:600)
>     at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:537)
>     at android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:418)
>     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stop(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:207)
>     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.stop(ExoPlayerImpl.java:357)
>     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.stop(SimpleExoPlayer.java:777)
>     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.stop(SimpleExoPlayer.java:772)
>     at package.ExoPlayerWrapper.stop(ExoPlayerWrapper.kt:xx)
>     at package.ExoPlayerWrapper.reset(ExoPlayerWrapper.kt:xx)
>     at package.ExoPlayerWrapper.playFromUrl(ExoPlayerWrapper.kt:xx)
>     at package.VideoPlayerActivity.onCreate(VideoPlayerActivity.kt:xx)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises from trying to use a player whose resources have already been released. Because:

```
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector)
```

only gets called once, during the initialization of `ExoPlayerWrapper`. If your activity is not restarted, then that instance of `ExoPlayerWrapper` sticks around with the released player.

Either create a new instance of `ExoPlayerWrapper` whenever you go to play your video, or create a player initialization method inside `ExoPlayerWrapper`, which you can call just before playing the video.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement no need to use release method. If you are using this method you should reinitialize exoplayer again.

You can use stop() method to stop the exoplayer.

Comment: But, as far as I understand, it's necessary to use release method - to avoid memory leaks. From ExoPlayer docs: "It’s important to release the player when it’s no longer needed, so as to free up limited resources such as video decoders for use by other applications. This can be done by calling ExoPlayer.release", https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html